# Is there any way to display specific area but mask around that area

Tags: unity-game-engine, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm dwelled on some problem and need some help or useful perspective to solve this problem.

I'm using Unity and [Bing Map SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/MapsSDK-Unity) I want to display only an area of map but the other areas must not be displayed and I want to mask that area somehow.
So, the problem is display an GeoBoundingBox area and mask or just ignore another area, and when zoomed in or out, this masked area or ignored area must be masked or ignored accordingly.

let make this problem more clear, say I want to display Turkey's map but the neighbouring country of Turkey's also displayed and zoomed accordingly and I want to masked or ignored all neighbouring country of Turkey and displayed only Turkey map.

For the sake of clarify, for example, with this [image](https://ibb.co/5TbbkB3), area that is under the black line must be masked and when user zoomed out or in, this area continued to mask accordingly.

Maybe there isn't a direct solution but a fresh perspective can be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about unity, but in general with maps, this is usually accomplished with these two steps:

1. Create a polygon of the globe and make your area of interest an inner ring of the polygon. This will represent all the area you don't want to focus on. You can then overlap this on the map and add color to it to hide that area. Here are a couple of examples in Azure Maps: https://samples.azuremaps.com/?search=mask
2. Optional. If you want to keep the user focused on that area (and reduce chance of them getting lost somewhere else in the world), restrict the map view to that focus area so they can't pan/zoom too far away from the area of interest.

Looking through the documentation for the Bing Maps Unity SDK, it doesn't appear to support polygons or restricting the map view. That said, the polygon mask is likely the most important for your scenario and since you don't need to interact with it you could work around this limitation by creating a custom tile layer that renders the polygon mask. You likely won't want to have to host a tile service online for this, but it look like there is a way in code to create a custom tile service with `TextureTileLayer`. https://github.com/microsoft/MapsSDK-Unity/wiki/TextureTileLayer

What you would have to do is instead of loading an image for a tile, you would create an image using a drawing tool and draw the polygon mask on top. Converting and shifting the polygon coordinates to tile coordinates is a bit tricky, the math is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/zoom-levels-and-tile-grid?tabs=csharp However, if as a first easy step, you could simply calculate the bounding box of each tile that is requested and if it does not includes your area of interest, simply make it a solid color, otherwise make it transparent. This will be blocky and will show a lot of surrounding area when zoomed out, but would be a lot easier to setup initially and experiment with getting a custom tile layer working.